# How to get a list of all recently published child pages?

Tags: child-pages, wp-list-pages

Can you please help me on how can I display a list `<li>` of newly published child pages.
I've been looking on google how to use display it using the `wp_list_pages();` but can't find out there. I want to display it like in the "Latest Trainings" or something like that.

Comment: Child pages of what parent?

Comment: I'll like to display child pages of all parents I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the post data for all child pages:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent__not_in'       => array(0),                               
    'no_found_rows'     => true,
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump(wp_list_pluck($child->posts,'post_title')); // debugging only
```

Then pass the IDs to `wp_list_pages()`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent__not_in'       => array(0),                               
    'no_found_rows'     => true,
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);
$ids = wp_list_pluck($child->posts,'ID');
$ids = implode($ids,',');
$args = array(
    'include'      => $ids,
);
wp_list_pages($args);
```

Or, even cleaner:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent__not_in'       => array(0),                               
    'no_found_rows'     => true,
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);
$args = array(
    'include'      => $child->posts,
);
wp_list_pages($args);
```

Please note that there is no error checking to that code.

I'll see if I can spot a clean way to do this with filters. Check back later.

Comment: how can I use it in a shortcode?

Comment: @KikoLolo One problem per question, if this is solved, then accept what solved it for you. You might find useful information here »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and generally at the [help]. [Ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) concerning your new problem.

Comment: sorry... I try the cleaner one but not showing up.

Comment: I am pretty sure I ran that code earlier and it worked. I can't re-test it right now.

Comment: See the following for a trivial shortcode sample: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98312/21376

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just looking to get a list of children with [`wp_list_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages), then you should use the `child_of` parameter to do so. But I'm assuming you're actually want to restrict that list to a certain time frame, for this `wp_list_pages()`, which uses [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), isn't really good equipped.

So I'm thinking you should use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) - or even [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) directly -, where you can make use of »[WP_Query: Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)«. <del>The drawback here - as a generic function`wp_list_posts()` does not exist - is that you have to write the code to generate your list yourself.</del> @s_ha_dum's [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/186055/22534) shows how you can combine this, making the drawback almost disappear - just a little bit more code is needed.

Comment: but how can i implement this variable(only child pages) using that get_posts() and im working to only limit the list to show something like show="5"

Comment: There are the parameters - see `WP_Query` documentation for details - `post_parent` and `post_parent__in` to show children, to regulate the number use `posts_per_page`. @KikoLolo

Comment: Take a closer look at s_ha_dum's [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/186055/22534), because it addresses the all children of all pages aspect and shows how to use it with `wp_list_pages`. @KikoLolo

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to generate the child pages.

```
<?php
// Set up the objects needed
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();

// Query all pages
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

$page_ids = get_all_page_ids();

$page_children = get_page_children( $page_ids, $all_wp_pages );

echo '<li>' . print_r( $page_children, true ) . '</li>';
?>
```